# Date as a synonym for anus

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, slang, ambiguity, australian-english

In the Song "Ten Foot Cock And A Few Hundred Virgins" Tim Minchin uses the phrase "it's a sin to take it up the date, even if it's great, even with your cowboy mate". I'm not a native English speaker - I have lived in the UK for a bit and consider my English to be quite good for a foreigner, but have never heard "date" used this way. Is it used in English in that way, am I mishearing it, is it an Australian thing, or did the singer just make it up to have something that rhymes?

Link to that moment of the song (most likely not safe for work):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXfmjMlPEic#t=85

Comment: There's a vague possibility that it's an Aussieism.

Comment: I would think it's referring to the "boyfriend/girlfriend" meaning of "date", and it "means" certain specific body parts only by way of metonymy.

Comment: Australian chiming in.  Yup, date is an infrequently used term for anus.  Also ring and freckle.  Someone scratching their bottom is often ribbed by being asked 'are you getting married soon?'  When they ask why, they're told because it looks like they are picking their ring, or picking the date. No sources just anecdotal, hence the comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @mcalex so it's not the "fruit" date that is used euphemistically, but the meaning of *date* as in "a romantic appointment"?

Comment: Australian comedians John Doyle and Greig Pickhaver used the term regularly in their roles as sports/political/life pundits Roy Slaven and HG Nelson.  I've always understood it to derive from a perceived visual resemblance.

Comment: There are many very infrequently used synomyms which rely heavily on context. In the song (love Tim, and the song btw), it's meaning is obvious because of the context, but it wouldn't work on it's own, unless this song, or the term became much more mainstream.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - consider the texture of the exterior of the fruit in question with that of the body part in question. This is the reason the word is used like that. The quip about the wedding date comes obviously, from picking at something said to resemble the fruit - it's (a wedding) the first thing that would come to mind generally if one was asked if they've picked or chosen a date yet.

Comment: Apologies for the long time before I un-accepted John Clifford's answer below and accepted the apparently correct one (I've been traveling).

I am a bit torn apart between the answers below, since rogermue came up with what seems to me like the more authoritative source; but I've chosen sumelic's because it's more comprehensive and incorporates rogermue's. I hope that's the right thing to do.

Either way, thanks to everyone!

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/XKFWE1xt_x0?t=1m38s) is an example of Roy & HG's use of the term in their commentary of gymnastics at the 2000 olympics.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Date* as a synonym of "anus" is Australian slang. The definitions I've found are a bit vague in terms of what specific anatomical feature it refers to (some say "anus," some say "buttocks"), but other people responding to this post have provided evidence that this vagueness may just be due to some dictionary-writers misunderstanding the meaning. (For example, [rogermue](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304529/date-as-a-synonym-for-anus/304544#304544) found a definition that says it can also mean "vagina," but [JEL](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304529/date-as-a-synonym-for-anus#comment687902_304534) found an [Ozwords link](http://ozwords.org/?p=4323#more-4323) where it says that "Later investigation concluded that the second meaning [vagina] was a furphy [[false report]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/furphy)." [Mark Cogan](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304529/date-as-a-synonym-for-anus/304534#comment688071_304534) says that "This was reasonably well-understood slang (meaning 'anus') when I was at university in Australia in the early 1990s; it never meant any other orifice or the buttocks in general.")

---

> *Date*: Asshole. Anus. Ex: *Did you see that? That guy just flashed his date at us.*

(["A Rough Guide to Australian Slang"](http://www.aussieontheroad.com/australian-slang/) from Aussie on the Road)

> **Date** : arse[hole] ("get off your fat date")

([Australian Slang Dictionary](http://www.koalanet.com.au/australian-slang.html#D) at Koala Net)

> **Date** Bum - bottom, arse. [Eg: get off your date]

("[Australian Slang Dictionary](http://aussie-slang.com/html/australian_slang.html)" at aussie-slang.com)

> **Date** - buttocks; a date roll is a roll of toilet paper.

("[Dictionary of Australian Slang](http://www.australiatravelsearch.com.au/trc/slang.html)" from Australia Travel Search)

I'm not Australian, so I can't describe this usage from a personal perspective.

Comment: Odd one this. A [more comprehensive dictionary of Australian slang](http://www.australianslang.org/index.php) doesn't touch it. Nor does the OED know anything about it.

Comment: Might be worth looking in a dictionary of Hiberno English if anyone has access.

Comment: 'Date' appears to be "slang of the month" or some such at [Ozwords](http://ozwords.org/). If you follow the "Continue reading" link, it appears the first recorded instance of the sense was in 1924.

Comment: You truly learn something new every day.

Comment: This was reasonably well-understood slang (meaning 'anus') when I was at university in Australia in the early 1990s; it never meant any other orifice or the buttocks in general.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd imagine it comes from referring to a bloke's female date as "a piece of arse" (and "phwoar look at that arse") ... and take it from there. Aussies are good at using abstractions to feed their slang habit. :)

Comment: @Mark Cogan I have contacted an Australian academic who says he has only heard this sense of date used as date hole = vagina. He has not heard it used as buttocks/anus but thinks it may be simply ignorance on the part of someone who "has not twigged". But Australian National Dictionary would seem to include both.

Comment: @PreferenceBean The use of 'date' to mean 'a romantic meeting', and by extension 'someone I'm spending the evening with' is (or was, 25 years ago) nowhere near as common in Australia as in the US (and, 'piece of ass' is also US slag not common in Australia). My assumption at the time was that 'date' stood for for 'anus' via visual metaphor, referring to the puckered brown fruit.

Comment: @MarkCogan: Aha!

Comment: @MarkCogan What you say there about Australia is just as relevant to the UK. It is not *piece of ass*, it is *piece of c++t*. So *piece of date* figures. You have got me wondering if it is an Australian euphemism for the dreaded c word.

Comment: @WS2 I don't recall *piece of X*, for any value of *X*, being in common usage; nor was there the exaggerated stigma attached to *cunt* that there is in the USA.

Answer (score 12):

The Australian National Dictionary has an entry for "date" meaning anus and vagina.
http://australiannationaldictionary.com.au/index.php

The link does not work well. You have to fill in "date" in the search field.

> 1919 W.H. Downing  *Digger Dialects 18*  *Date*, a word signifying contempt.]
>
> 1961 M. Calthorpe  *Dyehouse* 214 “In your bloody date! What do you
>   think we are?”
>
> 1971 B. Humphries  *Bazza pulls it Off*, “I hear tell the French tarts
>   … don’t say no to robbing the occasional date locker.”
>
> 1973 ‘Hogbotel & Ffuckes’  *Snatches & Lays* 25
>
> The Australian lady emu,
>   when she wants to find a mate,
>   Wanders round the desert
>   with a feather up her date.
>
> 1973 R. Edwards  Austral. *Bawdy Ballads* 26 “His doodle broke off and
>   stayed in her date.”

Hence **date** *v. trans.*, to ‘goose’ (a person).

> 1972 D. Hewett  *Bon-Bons & Roses* (1976) 52 “Remember when I got that
>   plumber in to unblock the sink? I was up on a chair fixing the new
>   curtains and he comes up behind, and dates me. Large as life.
>   Without a word of a lie. He dates me. Cheeky mug. And what did he
>   say? ‘Thought you might like your plumbing interfered with too,
>   Madam.’ ”

Comment: That is so interesting I have edited your answer to quote the entire entry. I am amazed that the OED has not picked this up, especially since the Australian National Dictionary is an OUP publication. It includes another expression *to goose a person* - which is also a new one on me.

Comment: *Goose*  v. OED definition *5. slang. To poke, tickle, etc., (a person) in a sensitive part, esp. the genital or anal regions; sometimes, more specifically, = fuck v. 1*.

Comment: I have contacted an Australian academic who says he has only heard this sense of *date* used as *date hole* = vagina. He has not heard it used as *buttocks* but thinks it may be simply ignorance on the part of someone who "has not twigged".

Comment: @WS2  Thanks for taking the trouble of consulting a person in Australia. The word date, AusE slang, seems to be a tricky case for lexicographers.

Answer (score 0):

As sumelic pointed out with an answer that should have been chosen instead of mine, it's Australian slang usually meaning "buttocks" but can be used for other body parts in the same region. There's a page about it at http://www.australiatravelsearch.com.au/trc/slang.html

Comment: I grew up in Australia. This is absolutely "real" slang and not something coined by Minchin.